# Nextjs Routing - Is there a way to START at the top when switching pages? GSAP-related

Tags: scroll, routes, next.js, gsap, scrolltrigger

Here's the scenario I'm coming across that's affecting my GSAP ScrollTrigger animations:

I have a home page that loads and animates.
When I scroll down the home page, scroll trigger behaves normally.
When I get to the bottom and decide to use the navbar to navigate to another page (I'm using the Nextjs `<Link>` component here), it sends me to the new page but starts at the BOTTOM Of the new page and quickly scrolls to the TOP of the new page.

This is a problem because it triggers all of my GSAP animations simultaneously for that page.

Is there a way to switch to a new page but START at the top— rather than start where ever you are in the y-position and scrolling to the top of the new page?

Essentially what's happening is that when I click on a `<Link`> component in Nextjs, the y-position of my viewport is retained during page transition. Once I'm on the new page, I'm still on that same y-position of the previous page, but then it SCROLLS to the top. This is bad because it triggers all of my GSAP animations.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it!

I needed to override the `scroll-behavior: smooth;` with `scroll-behavior: auto !important;`.

I basically put `scroll-behavior: auto !important;` at the root `:root {}`.